# PHP MySQL New Lines / Whitespaces from textarea

Tags: php, mysql, json

I've a problem about whitespaces and new lines at the beginning of a textarea.
I send a json string with ajax to the php script.
Then I decode the string into an php array (with json_decode).
So I have a string in this array with two line breaks at the beginning.
If a print the text from the array, the line breaks are there, but if I store the text into the mysql database, the line breaks are gone...
Only at the beginning of the string, the line breaks gone... At the rest of the string, the line breaks are ok.

Thanks for your answers!
rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most browsers textareas' value parsed in a way, that the first character is ignored if it's a new-line.

```
<textarea>Value</textarea> <!-- value will be "Value" -->

<textarea>
Value
</textarea> <!-- value will be "Value\n" -->

<textarea>

Value

</textarea> <!-- value will be "\nValue\n\n" -->
```

Checked using javascript in Chrome / FF / Opera.

Comment: thanks for this answer. now i add a \n at the beginning of the string and it works fine! thank you

Comment: Beware: if there's no new-line at the point, when the textarea rendered, it will pollute end-user's data (with additional new-lines). But it'll be stripped next time, the textarea edited; so it's a border-line case.

Answer (score 0):

Probably(hopefully) you are doing some escaping / sanitizing before you store in the database. That probably trims your result, while in pure php the result is not trimmed.

Comment: `mysql_query("INSERT INTO page (number,subnumber,name,fk_template,title,content,footer,enabled) VALUES('".$infos->number."','".$i."','".$infos->name."','".$infos->template."','".$page->title."','".$page->content."','".$page->footer."','".$infos->active."');");`
This is my code. I removed the mysql_real_escape_string before, but now I have loose the first \n on each save

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to make sure that you information stays the way it needs to be saved. Then add to database. When retrieving, call [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to get all of you lovely information back.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this is the opposite of my question. i need the whitespaces and line breaks

Comment: hi, the same problem as on the first answer. the first \n will be deleted.... but only the first, if i have 6 \n at the beginning, php/mysql store 5 and so on...

Comment: Could you update your question with some code so we can try to replicate the result?